# How can I tile an image within a given area of a page in my document, using the Mako SDK?

Tags: c++, pdf, xps, mako-sdk

I'm looking to use an image for tilling, to fill and area of my page, in my document.

I've seen that there is an `IDOMImage` and `IDOMImageBrush`, but I'm not sure how to use them in order to scale and tile my source image.

How can I do this with the Mako SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mako can tile an image into a given area, and also flip alternate tiles to create a pattern. Use a scaling transform to control its size. This code shows you how.

```
// Declare an output pointer
IOutputPtr output;

// Create new assembly, document and page
IDocumentAssemblyPtr assembly = IDocumentAssembly::create(jawsMako);
IDocumentPtr document = IDocument::create(jawsMako);
IPagePtr page = IPage::create(jawsMako);

// Add the page to the document, and the document to the assembly
document->appendPage(page);
assembly->appendDocument(document);

// Create a fixed page to work with
double pageWidth = 10 * 96.0;
double pageHeight = 20 * 96.0;
IDOMFixedPagePtr fixedPage = IDOMFixedPage::create(jawsMako, pageWidth, pageHeight);

// Load the image file into an image
IDOMImagePtr image = IDOMJPEGImage::create(jawsMako, IInputStream::createFromFile(jawsMako, imageFilePath));

// Find its dimensions
IImageFramePtr frame;
image->getFirstImageFrame(jawsMako, frame);
double imageWidth = frame->getWidth();
double imageHeight = frame->getHeight();

// Create a rect to hold the image
FRect printBounds(0.0, 0.0, pageWidth, pageHeight);

// Create a transformation matrix to scale the image, taking into account the page proportions
// Scaling factor is a float ranging from 0.0 to 1.0
double pageWidthHeightRatio = pageWidth / pageHeight;
FMatrix transform;
transform.scale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor * pageWidthHeightRatio);

// Stick the image in a brush
IDOMBrushPtr imageBrush = IDOMImageBrush::create(jawsMako, image, FRect(), printBounds, transform, 1.0, eFlipXY);

// And now create a path using the image brush
IDOMPathNodePtr path = IDOMPathNode::createFilled(jawsMako, IDOMPathGeometry::create(jawsMako, printBounds), imageBrush);

// Add the path to the fixed page
fixedPage->appendChild(path);

// This becomes the page contents
page->setContent(fixedPage);

// Write to the output
output = IPDFOutput::create(jawsMako);
output->writeAssembly(assembly, outputFilePath);
```

Using this code, with this image:

[image: Original Image]

Produced this tilled image:

[image: Tiled Image]

The code uses an enum, eTileXY. These are the available tiling options:

**eTilingMode**
Tiling mode type enumeration.

**eNoTile**
No tiling. If the area to be painted is larger than the image, just paint the image once (in the location specified by the brush's viewport), and leave the remaining area transparent.

**eTile**
Tile image without any flipping or rotating of the image. A square image consisting of a single diagonal line between opposite corners would produce diagonal lines when tiled in this mode.

**eFlipX**
Tile image such that alternate columns of tiles are flipped horizontally. A square image consisting of a single diagonal line between opposite corners would produce chevrons running horizontally across the area when tiled in this mode.

**eFlipY**
Tile image such that alternate rows of tiles are flipped vertically. A square image consisting of a single diagonal line between opposite corners would produce chevrons running vertically across the area when tiled in this mode.

**eFlipXY**
Tile image such that alternate columns of tiles are flipped horizontally AND alternate rows of tiles are flipped vertically. A square image consisting of a single diagonal line between opposite corners would produce a grid of squares balanced on their points when tiled in this mode.